# subprocess python Popen to open java jar

Tags: java, python, subprocess

I am new to python subprocess and i do not understand the documentation.

I am trying to run a jar file within my python program and pipe the output back to python.

```
sys.stdout.write("haha")

subprocess.Popen(['java', 'myjarfile.jar'], stdin= subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
ans = raw_input("")
```

However, this does not seem to work

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you expect `sys.stdout.write()` and `raw_input()` to achieve in this case?

Comment: wording and linewrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass `b'haha'` bytestring as an input to the `java` child process and to get its stdout as `ans` bytestring:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import check_output

ans = check_output(['java', '-jar', 'myjarfile.jar'], input=b'haha')
```

`input` parameter is supported only since Python 3.4, you could use `.communicate()` on older Python versions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(['java', '-jar', 'myjarfile.jar'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
ans = p.communicate(b'haha')[0]
if p.returncode != 0:
   raise Error
```